# Proving the Boolean expressions

Tags: proof-verification, self-learning, boolean-algebra

[image]

Are these two Boolean expressions the same?

*$co$ is the carry out while $ci$ is the carry in.

Comment: Please define $co,ci$

Comment: Thanks for telling me, I have defined.

Answer (score 1):

Since $a+b = a \oplus b +ab$, we have 
\begin{eqnarray}
c_{o} &=& ab+c_{in} (a+b) \\
&=& ab+c_{in} (a \oplus b+ab) \\
&=& ab+c_{in} a \oplus b+c_{in} ab \\
&=& ab+c_{in} a \oplus b
\end{eqnarray}
(Since $x+yx = x$.)